# Listview - Drag & Drop cursor to PC desktop

Tags: vb.net, listview

I'm using a function to change my cursor to icon when dragging item from Listview to PC Desktop. Cursor works when I drag item directly from "floating" window to desktop, but It changes when I try to drag It from Listview which is embedded inside another control (which is my case). In another words, when cursor leaves Listview and touches another control on my form (such as Panel), my cursor changes to something like image below:

[image]

How could I obtain My cursor same all the way until I drop Item ? Here is my code so far:

```
 Private Sub Listview1_ItemDrag(sender As Object, e As ItemDragEventArgs) Handles Listview1.ItemDrag

        Dim Lview As System.Windows.Forms.ListView = DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.ListView)
        Dim filecollection As New ArrayList

        If Lview.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then

            For Each myItem In Lview.SelectedItems

                If File.Exists(myItem.Tag.ToString) Then

                    filecollection.Add(myItem.Tag.ToString)

                ElseIf Directory.Exists(myItem.Tag.ToString) Then

                    filecollection.Add(myItem.Tag.ToString)

                End If

            Next

                    Dim result = Lview.DoDragDrop(New DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, DirectCast(IzbraniPredmeti.ToArray(GetType(String)), String())), DragDropEffects.Copy)

            If result = DragDropEffects.Copy Then

                Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
            End If

        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub Listview1_GiveFeedback(sender As Object, e As GiveFeedbackEventArgs) Handles Listview1.GiveFeedback

        e.UseDefaultCursors = False

        Dim Lview As System.Windows.Forms.ListView = DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.ListView)
        Dim img As New Bitmap(MyImageList.Images(CacheShellIcon(Lview.SelectedItems(0).Tag.ToString)))
        Me.Cursor = my_functions.CreateCursor(img) 'function to create cursor

    End Sub

    Private Sub Listview1_DragOver(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles Listview1.DragOver

        Dim Lview As System.Windows.Forms.ListView = DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.ListView)

        If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy

        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: The cursor is determined by the control it is over - whether they will accept DnD at all, whether they will accept that data format and whether they will accept that operation (based on whether the Ctrl or Shift key is pressed).  Even DnDs started by Explorer work that way.  It how any given windows app tell the user whether or not they can/should drop on that thing

Comment: @Plutonix, so what you are saying is that I should implement every control's cursor to same dragged cursor If I'm over them with mouse ? Then WHY, If I comment out ***Listview_GiveFeedback*** to have any custom cursor this occurs - While in Listview cursor is Default (meaning when you drag you get that "***+***" sign), when you drag over another control you get same "no cursor" (as posted image in my question), but when you leave app and reach PC Desktop you get Default cursor with  "***+***" sign again ??. I just want same trick, but with custom cursor.